# Selenium JUnit tests not running org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have created a java/selenium/cucumber automation framework with 4 feature files each testing different functional area's.

I can run each of these within Eclipse as feature files and they all run fine.

However I am trying to figure out how I can run them all as a JUnit test so that I can generate the extent reports.

I run the mainRunner class as a Junit test like ..

The first feature runs fine but then the next three do not. A chrome browser is opened for each of these but
the site is not navigated to. The error

```
'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?'
```

is shown in the console logs.

So is this issue to do with how I have set my feature files up to use the startBrowser, initBrowser and closeBrowser methods. Which are
defined in a seperate class 'BrowserInitTearDownStepDefinitions'?

All my feature files look like ..

```
Feature: Update a Computer in Database
  -- left out details

@StartBrowser
Scenario: Start browser session
  When I initialize driver
  Then open browser
  
@MyTest4
Scenario Outline: Update a computer
    -- left our details
Examples: 
    -- left out details 
    
@CloseBrowser
Scenario: Close the browser
    Then close browser
```

I have had a look at the other posts related to this message that reference the same error, but can't see a clear cut solution.

As the error would indicate I seem to be quitting the driver but then not reinitialising it for the next test. Although Im not sure why this
would be the case given that each feature file has the @StartBrowser and @CloseBrowser tags which should execute these methods. Below is my BrowserInitTearDownStepDefinitions class.

```
public class BrowserInitTearDownStepDefinitions {
    //Initialises Chrome browser
    @When("^I initialize driver$")
    public void initializeDriver() {
        System.out.println("initializeDriver runs");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\xxxx\\CucumberAutomationFramework\\src\\test\\java\\cucumberAutomationFramework\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriverUtils.setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        
    }
    //Opens Chrome browser and clicks in search input box
    @Then("^open browser$")
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.out.println("Open Browser runs");
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://computer-database.gatling.io/computers");        
    }
    
    //Closes browser after all scenarios run and deletes cookies
    @Then("^close browser$")
    public void closeBrowser() {
        System.out.println("Close Browser runs");
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.quit();
        driver =null;
    }
}
```

I create a new instance of the webdriver within my stepDefs file with ..

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver()
```

The webdriver utils class code is ..

package cucumberAutomationFramework.utilityClasses;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class WebDriverUtils {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    public static void setDriver(WebDriver webDdriver) {
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = webDdriver;
        }
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("Driver is null. Initialize driver before calling this method.");
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: WebDriverUtils doesn't seem like the proper place to keep the driver.  Include that code in your post.  Are you sure only one instance of Chrome is launched?

Comment: Hi, I've done that. Im not sure actually. I perhaps need to run it in debug mode.

Comment: I don't think you want "static" there.  You want an instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, I just realise I instantiate the driver from within openBrowser in my BrowserInitTearDownStepDefinitions class as well.

Comment: you probably want to move it out of that class... not familiar with the framework... but also it's set to private, so driver.quit and driver=null should be in a method of that class.  I'm sort of surprised that driver.quit() was working from that closebrowser method.

Comment: To be honest, this solution was provided from the answer to another question that I posted. If I remove all the static method modifiers from WebDriverUtils then it causes errors in my other classes that are using the class WebDriverUtils  like 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDriver() from the type WebDriverUtils'. I got in to a bit of an endless loop where fixing errors in one class would cause errors in another.